# Can I send commands to operative system from Adobe AIR Desktop Application?

Tags: actionscript-3, command-line, air

In Python there is a function: `os.system(command)` that runs the `command` passed by parameter in the command line, there is something similar in AS3 (or MXML) running an Adobe AIR Desktop Application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the incoming [Air2.0](http://blogs.adobe.com/air/2009/11/adobe_air_2_beta_now_available.html) you will be able to execute native process (with some restriction), [here](http://mchristoff.com/category/code/air/) an example controling mplayer from an Air application. 
Otherwise it s not possible within Air 1.0-1.5